# Explanation for perl quine

Tags: perl, quine

I found this quine recently

```
$a='$a=%c%s%c;printf($a,39,$a,39,10);%c';printf($a,39,$a,39,10);
```

And I just can't get my head around it. I've found no explanation on google/SO for this particular one, so I'm hoping that someone could explain to me how that thing works :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `printf` parameters and substitute them by hand,

(`39` is single quote, `'`, and `10` is newline `\n` when interpreted as `%c`)
so `$a` which start as

```
$a=%c%s%c;printf($a,39,$a,39,10);%c
```

becomes (replaced chars marked below with `^`)

```
$a='%s%c;printf($a,39,$a,39,10);%c
   ^ (first %c replaced)
$a='$a=%c%s%c;printf($a,39,$a,39,10);%c%c;printf($a,39,$a,39,10);%c
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ (%s replaced)
$a='$a=%c%s%c;printf($a,39,$a,39,10);%c';printf($a,39,$a,39,10);%c
                                       ^ (second %c replaced)
```

and finally

```
$a='$a=%c%s%c;printf($a,39,$a,39,10);%c';printf($a,39,$a,39,10);\n
                                             (last %c replaced) ^^
```

Answer (score 5):

This code is consisted of two lines.

A variable assignment:

```
$a='$a=%c%s%c;printf($a,39,$a,39,10);%c';
```

And a [printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html):

```
printf($a,39,$a,39,10)
```

First of all let's learn a few things about `printf`. If you check the [sprintf documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) you will see that `printf('%c',39)` will print the 39th character which is `'`, while the `printf('%c',10)` is a newline `\n`. Another thing to keep in mind is that `printf` takes a list of parameters which means that `printf('%s%s','foo','bar')` will print `foobar`.

So now it should be clear that `printf($a,39,$a,39,10)` takes the format from `$a` and does the following 4 conversions (equal to the number of `%` signs in the `$a` string)

- uses the 2nd argument `39` for the 1st occurrence of `%c` (check the `$a` variable),
- then it uses the string `$a` for `%s`
- the 4th argument `39` of the `printf` for the next `%c`
- and finally the `10` for the last `%c`

which results in a copy of its own source code.